# Persistent: CRUD TypeClass

Tags: haskell, crud, persistent, yesod

I am trying to write a typeclass that simplifies writing a CRUD backend using *persistent*, *aeson* and *scotty*

Here is my idea:

```
runDB x = liftIO $ do info <- mysqlInfo
                      runResourceT $ SQL.withMySQLConn info $ SQL.runSqlConn x

class (J.FromJSON a, J.ToJSON a, SQL.PersistEntity a) => CRUD a where
    getBasePath :: a -> String
    getCrudName :: a -> String

    getFromBody :: a -> ActionM a
    getFromBody _ = do body <- jsonData
                       return body

    mkInsertRoute :: a -> ScottyM ()
    mkInsertRoute el =
        do post (fromString ((getBasePath el) ++ "/" ++ (getCrudName el))) $ do
                body <- getFromBody el
                runDB $ SQL.insert body
                json $ J.Bool True

    mkUpdateRoute :: a -> ScottyM ()
    mkDeleteRoute :: a -> ScottyM ()
    mkGetRoute :: a -> ScottyM ()
    mkGetAllRoute :: a -> ScottyM ()
```

This doesn't compile, I get this error:

```
Could not deduce (SQL.PersistEntityBackend a
                  ~ Database.Persist.GenericSql.Raw.SqlBackend)
from the context (CRUD a)
  bound by the class declaration for `CRUD'
  at WebIf/CRUD.hs:(18,1)-(36,36)
Expected type: SQL.PersistEntityBackend a
  Actual type: SQL.PersistMonadBackend
                 (SQL.SqlPersist (Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.ResourceT IO))
In the second argument of `($)', namely `SQL.insert body'
In a stmt of a 'do' block: runDB $ SQL.insert body
In the second argument of `($)', namely
  `do { body <- getFromBody el;
        runDB $ SQL.insert body;
        json $ J.Bool True }'
```

It seems like I have to add another type-constraint, something like `PersistMonadBackend m ~ PersistEntityBackend a`, but I don't see how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constraint means that the associated backend type for a [`PersistEntity`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-0.8.0.2/docs/Database-Persist-Store.html#t%3aPersistEntity) instance needs to be `SqlBackend`, so when a user implements the `PersistEntity` class as part of implementing the `CRUD` class they will need to specify that.

From your point of view, you just need to enable the `TypeFamilies` extension and add that constraint to your class definition:

```
class ( J.FromJSON a, J.ToJSON a, SQL.PersistEntity a
      , SQL.PersistEntityBackend a ~ SQL.SqlBackend
      ) => CRUD a where
    ...
```

When defining an instance of `PersistEntity` for some type `Foo`, the user of `CRUD` will need to define the `PersistEntityBackend` type to be `SqlBackend`:

```
instance PersistEntity Foo where
    type PersistEntityBackend Foo = SqlBackend
```

Here's my complete copy of your code that passes the GHC type-checker:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import Control.Monad.Logger
import Control.Monad.Trans
import qualified Data.Aeson as J
import Data.Conduit
import Data.String ( fromString )
import qualified Database.Persist.Sql as SQL
import Web.Scotty

-- incomplete definition, not sure why this instance is now needed
-- but it's not related to your problem
instance MonadLogger IO

-- I can't build persistent-mysql on Windows so I replaced it with a stub
runDB x = liftIO $ runResourceT $ SQL.withSqlConn undefined $ SQL.runSqlConn x

class ( J.FromJSON a, J.ToJSON a, SQL.PersistEntity a
      , SQL.PersistEntityBackend a ~ SQL.SqlBackend
      ) => CRUD a where

    getBasePath :: a -> String
    getCrudName :: a -> String

    getFromBody :: a -> ActionM a
    getFromBody _ = do body <- jsonData
                       return body

    mkInsertRoute :: a -> ScottyM ()
    mkInsertRoute el =
        do post (fromString ((getBasePath el) ++ "/" ++ (getCrudName el))) $ do
                body <- getFromBody el
                runDB $ SQL.insert body
                json $ J.Bool True

    mkUpdateRoute :: a -> ScottyM ()
    mkDeleteRoute :: a -> ScottyM ()
    mkGetRoute :: a -> ScottyM ()
    mkGetAllRoute :: a -> ScottyM ()
```

Comment: Thanks! :-) I've ended up with something like that too, but I'd really like it to work with all Persistent backends, not just the SQL based ones. I know that the current runDB enforces this, so I think I probably need even more abstraction.

Comment: The constraint is coming from the default implementation of mkInsertRoute. Perhaps you should remove the default from the class definition, or abstract over the `runDB $ SQL.insert` bit?

Comment: I think it's enough to abstract over `runDB`?

Comment: The type signature for insert is `insert :: (PersistMonadBackend m ~ PersistEntityBackend val, PersistEntity val) => val -> m (Key val)`, it would work with any backend.

Comment: Fair enough, was just misled by where it was being imported from.